# Show that $N$ is a normal subgroup in $G$ when $N$ is the intersection of normal subgroups in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

**QUESTION** : Let $G$ be a group, let $X$ be a set, and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $$N = \bigcap_{g\in G} gHg^{-1}$$ Show that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ cointained in $H$.

**MY ATTEMPT**: I began by asking myself precisely what $\bigcap_{g\in G} gHg^{-1}$ means. I concluded that it must mean that if $g_1, g_2, g_3, ... , g_n \in G$ then $N$ might just be $$ g_1H{g_1}^{-1} \cap g_2H{g_2}^{-1} \cap g_3H{g_3}^{-1} \cap ... g_nH{g_n}^{-1}$$ which I figured is actually just $H$ because that's the only element that all those elements have in common.

Therefore I figured that $N=H$.

Now my problem comes in showing that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. I've never been good at that.

Comment: $H$ need not be normal. And $H$ is not necessarily contained in all those subgroups.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft What? How can $H$ not be in all those subgroups? I did say that I think $N=H$ so if the question asks that I prove $N$ is normal and I prove that $H$ is normal, isn't that the same thing?

Comment: But $H\neq N$ unless $H$ is normal. If $H$ is not normal, there is no reason why you would have $H\subseteq gHg^{-1}$ for some arbitrary $g\in G$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft  I'm still super confused though. I think I may have to go back to doing some reading. Am I completely off with my attempt?

Comment: Well, you are correct in what it means (ie, that long line of intersections). But you seem to have misunderstood something if you think $H$ is always contained in $gHg^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can you explain to me why $H$ is $not$ in the huge intersection?

Comment: $H$ is in the big intersection if and only if $H$ is in each of the subgroups you intersect. But these are subgroups of the form $gHg^{-1}$. You should try with a few examples in $S_3$ (take a subgroup of order $2$) to see that these need not contain $H$.

Comment: Ok! I will try what you have suggested and change my approach. Thank you

Comment: See also: [Intersection of conjugate subgroups is normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/369629).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have several good answers, and have probably completed the question yourself, but I'd like to provide my point of view.

Begin with two trivial observations:

1. Since one of the components of the intersection is $H$ conjugated by the identity, $N\subseteq H$.
2. Any intersection of subgroups is a subgroup.

Together these facts give you that $N$ is a subgroup of $H$.  Therefore, the main part of the proof is normality.  Now, ask yourself the following question:

> What are you gonna conjugate $N$ by so that the result isn't in $N$?

In particular, my claim is that when we conjugate $N$ by some $x\in G$, we are simply inducing a permutation of the components of the intersection, which of course does not change the resulting content.  Can you see why this is true?

> $\displaystyle N^x=\left(\bigcap_{g\in G}H^g\right)^x=\bigcap_{g\in G}(H^g)^x=\bigcap_{g\in G}H^{gx}=\bigcap_{k\in Gx}H^{k}=\bigcap_{y\in G}H^y=N$

It's easy to visualize: like a pinwheel, permuting the leaves does not change the bulb.

**Now let's look at this from a different angle.**

We know that we can't form a quotient group from $H$ unless $H$ is normal.  But let's try anyway and see what we get.

> Let $G$ act on the right coset space $G\backslash H$ by right multiplication.  What is the kernel of this action?

Explicitly, this means "given the homomorphism $\theta:G\rightarrow \operatorname{Sym}(G\backslash H)$ by $\theta(g)=\theta_g$ where $\theta_g(Ha)=H(ag)$, what is $\operatorname{ker}(\theta)$?"  or, more simply, "for which $k\in G$ does $Hak=Ha$ hold for all $a\in G$?

> $Hak=Ha$ if and only if $Haka^{-1}=H$ if and only if $aka^{-1}\in H$.

If this is true for all $a\in G$, then in particular it is true for $a=\operatorname{id}_G$, so $k\in H$.  Furthermore, the set of these $k$ must be normal in $G$ (as expected, since kernels are always normal).  Since all such $k$ are contained in $\operatorname{ker}(\theta)$, we must then have that **$N=\operatorname{ker}(\theta)$ is precisely the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$.**

In this way, we see that $G/N$ is the *best we can do* when trying to make a quotient group from a not-necessarily-normal subgroup $H$.

Hopefully this provides some motivation and/or intuition towards this problem and why it matters.

Comment: THANK YOU - this is the kind of answer I needed to see :)

Comment: @AlexanderGruber : The map $\theta$ you defined is an anti-homomorphism $\theta(gh)=\theta(h)\circ\theta(g)$, isn't it? See my comment below to the answer of Babak S.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $H\leq G$ and let $\Omega$ be the set of all $Ha$ where $a\in G$. Define an action like: $$(Ha)^x=Hax,~~ Ha,Hax\in\Omega;~~x\in G$$ By this action we see that the stabilizer of $Ha$ for example is $a^{-1}Ha$. Now try to show that the map $x\mapsto\bar{x},~~\bar{x}(Ha)=Hax$ is a homomorphism with the kernel $N$.

Comment: Thank you! That is an interesting method. So I don't have to use any of the information offered in the question? Or....

Comment: @Siyanda: I am with Tobias in his leading comments.

Comment: @babakS. I'm still super confused though. I think I may have to go back to doing some reading. Am I completely off with my attempt?

Comment: Ah,  this is *my* approach. Excellent answer! +1

Comment: @Siyanda, yes: you're completely off since your approach seems to be *forcing* on you to show something false, namely $\,N=H\,$ . This is not so, as you were already explained...perhaps your confusion is due to the fact that, for some reason, you seem to believe that H is contained in each of its conjugates, which is completely false.

Comment: @Siyanda: You'r welcome.

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy.

Comment: @BabakS. I think you defined a right action here and hence the map : $x\mapsto\bar{x}$ is an anti-homomorphism : $\overline{xy}=\bar{y}\circ\bar{x}$. It's not a real issue if we work with left cosets $G/H$ or if we change the action by taking inverse : $\bar{x}(Ha)=Hax^{-1}$. I just emphasize this to make sure my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your $N$ is normally denoted as $core_G(H)$, the **largest** normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$.

Comment: *Note*: I have also seen $\operatorname{core}_G(H)$ written as $H_G$ in some texts.

Comment: Yes, good point, some texts use that