# When are finite-index subgroups of a Lie group closed?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group (or, if necessary, a reductive Lie group) and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. If $\lbrack G:H\rbrack < \infty$, is it true that $H$ is closed? If not, are there any broad assumptions on $G$ which make this true?

Comment: For a start: if $H$ is closed, then every coset of $H$ is closed, so the complement of $H$ is closed, so $H$ is open and $G$ is disconnected.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is true. It suffices to show that any homomorphism $\pi : G \to F$ from a Lie group $G$ to a finite group $F$ (with the discrete topology) is continuous, or equivalently has the property that its kernel contains the connected component $G_0$ of the identity in $G$. To prove this it suffices to show that some neighborhood $U$ of the identity in $G$ is contained in the kernel. Pick a neighborhood $U$ which is contained in the image of the exponential map $\exp : \mathfrak{g} \to G$. Then for any $g \in U$ there exists some one-parameter subgroup $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \to G_0$ such that $\varphi(1) = g$. I claim that the composition $\pi \circ \varphi : \mathbb{R} \to F$ is constant, from which the conclusion follows.

But this is clear. The image of any such homomorphism is necessarily a [divisible group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group), and the trivial group is the only divisible finite group.

Comment: Hm, wish I knew you were typing such a similar (and more succinct!) answer while I was.  +1 from me.  I'll delete my momentarily.

Comment: @Jason: I think you should keep your answer around. The details are helpful and I omitted a lot of them.

Comment: Fair enough.  I suppose details never hurt anyone

Answer (score 7):

If $H\subseteq G$ is finite index, then $H$ is made out of components of $G$.  In particular, $H$ is closed (and open) in $G$.

(This proof is heavily borrowed from [The Lie theory of connected Pro-Lie groups](http://books.google.com/books?id=fJyqSkEexNgC&pg=PA406&lpg=PA406&dq=connected%20lie%20groups%20have%20no%20finite%20index%20subgroups.&source=bl&ots=4ca1IfOUFe&sig=bn_LL4HLgl3B3xsmciWwmbP-Ips&hl=en&sa=X&ei=57T1UfuvMsfrqQG-pIC4Cg&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=connected%20lie%20groups%20have%20no%20finite%20index%20subgroups.&f=false), by Hoffman and Morris, though I honestly couldn't tell you what a Pro-Lie group is!)

**Lemma 0:**  We may assume $G$ is connected.

**Proof:**  If $G^0$ denotes the identity component of $G$, then $H\cap G^0 \subseteq G^0$ is finite index.  This follows because the inclusion map $i:G^0\rightarrow G$ induces an injective map $i:G^0/(H\cap G^0)\rightarrow G/H$.   The map $i$ is injective, because if $i([g_1]) = i([g_2])$, then $g_1 = g_2 h$ for some $h\in H$.  Then $g_2^{-1} g_1 = h\in H$.  Since $G^0$ is a subgroup of $G$, this implies  $h\in G^0$, so $g_1 \cong g_2 \in G^0/(H\cap G^0).$  Since $i$ is injective, we have $|G^0/(H\cap G^0)|\leq |G/H| = [G:H]$.

**Lemma 1:**  $G$ is generated by its divisible subgroups.

Proof:  There is an open set $U\subseteq G$ for which the exponential map $\exp:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow G$ is onto.  Since every connected Lie group is generated by an open set around $e$, it's enough to show that every element in $U$ lies in a divisible subgroup of $G$.

But, if $u = \exp(X)\in U$, then $u$ lies in the divisible subgroup $\{exp(tX):t\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

**Lemma 2**:  We may assume wlog that $H$ is normal.

**Proof**:

Suppose $G = g_1 H \cup ... \cup g_n H$.  Then $N = \bigcap_{i=1}^n g_i H g_i^{-1}$ is finite index and normal.

**Lemma 3**:  $H = G$.

**Proof**:  Assuming $H$ is normal, we have a group homomorphism $\pi:G\rightarrow G/H$ onto a finite group.  But since $G$ is generated by its divisible subgroups, so is $\pi(G) = G/H$.  But since $G/H$ is finite, it has no nontrivial divisible groups.  Thus, $G/H$ is trivial, i.e., $H = G$.

Comment: Looking back on this 6 years later, in the proof of Lemma 1, I mean there is an open set $U\subseteq G$ for which $U\subseteq \exp(\mathfrak{g})$.  That edit doesn't seem to be worth bumping this question to the top...

Comment: I think this answer is very much detailed, but actually I cannot see why $N$ is finite index and normal....

Comment: I've got some information from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120685/subgroup-of-finite-index-contains-a-normal-subgroup-of-finite-index).

Comment: @Kei:  The intersection is finite index by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128538/does-the-intersection-of-two-finite-index-subgroups-have-finite-index and induction.  Normality follows from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369629/intersection-of-conjugate-subgroups-is-normal together with the fact that for any $g\in G$, $gH = g_iH$ for some $i$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Finite index subgroup intersection lemma you have introduced to me is more general and useful I think.