# Stabilizer, Kernel and Orbit of the right action.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

If $G$ act on the set of all right cosets of a subgroup $K$ then I have the following questions:-

1. What is the stabilizer of an element $Kx$.
2. What is the kernel of the Action.
3. What is the orbit of $Kx$.

My attempt ( I know its short):-

1. $Stb_G(Kx)=\{g\in G : Kxg=Kx\}$.
2. $Ker = \{g\in G : Kxg=Kx \, \, \mbox{for all} \,  Kx \}$ also I know the Ker is intersection of all stabilizer but since the stabilizer is not nice not sure if useful to use it.
3. Okay the action is transitive, but not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1, it follows from what you wrote that $xg=k'x$ for some $k'\in K$, so $g=x^{-1}k'x$ and the answer is that the the stabilizer is $x^{-1}Kx$.

The kernel is, as you say, the intersection of all $x^{-1}K x$ for all $x\in G$. I'm not sure if it has a name: in case of commutative groups it is all of $K$, in some cases it can even be trivial. (It is always a [normal subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369629/intersection-of-conjugate-subgroups-is-normal) of $G$.)

For transitivity, note that, in a group, you can convert an element $kx$ to any other element by suitable right multiplication.

Comment: The kernel of any action is normal. In this case, $\bigcap_{x \in G}x^{-1}Kx$ is called the **core** of $K$, and it has the property that it is the largest subgroup of $K$ which is normal in $G$.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 2):

You can express the stabilizer more concisely by observing that $Kxg = Kx$ if and only if $xg \in Kx$ if and only if $g \in x^{-1}Kx$. Therefore the stabilizer of $Kx$ is $x^{-1}Kx$.

Then the kernel is $\bigcap_{x \in G} x^{-1}Kx$, which is often called the core of $K$ in $G$.

To see that the action is transitive, simply observe that $Ky = Kxg$ is satisfied by $g = x^{-1}y$.