# Proving that a group of order $p^nq$ for primes $p$ and $q$ is not simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> Prove that a group of order $p^nq$ for primes $p$ and $q$ is not simple.

I've been able to prove the theorem holds for $p=q$ and $p>q$. If $p<q$ the best I've been able to do is use Sylow to show: $$p^n+p^{n-1}-1\leq q$$
Yet I seem to be stuck. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: See https://coolnumbers.wordpress.com/2012/10/31/finite-groups-of-order-pn-q-are-solvable/

Comment: @Bach It's essentially the same: to show it's solvable, you show it's not simple and use induction...

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. Suppose $P$ is not normal.

Consider $n_p$, the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups conjugate to $P$. By Sylow, $n_p | q$ so since $n_p \neq 1$ it must equal $q$.

Note that the set of $p$-Sylow subgroups is exactly the set of subgroups conjugate to $P$. All these groups have the same order, so are all $p$-Sylow subgroups, and all $p$-Sylow subgroups are conjugate. Furthermore, the intersection of the subgroups conjugate to $P$ is normal. (See [Intersection of conjugate subgroups is normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369629/intersection-of-conjugate-subgroups-is-normal).) So, exploring the possibility that $G$ is simple, suppose that intersection is trivial.

Then the total number of non-trivial elements in all $p$-Sylow subgroups is $(p^n-1)q$. That leaves exactly $p^nq - (p^n-1)q - 1 = q-1$ non-trivial elements among all $q$-Sylow subgroups.

Each $q$-Sylow subgroup has order $q$, so it has $q-1$ non-trivial elements, so there is only one such subgroup which is therefore normal.

To recap: either the $p$-Sylow subgroup is normal, the intersection of all $p$-Sylow subgroups is non-trivial and normal, or the $q$-Sylow subgroup is normal.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo Thanks for your feedback. I edited the proof to try and address your concern. Did that sort it?

Comment: Why is the number of non-trivial elements in the $p$-Sylow subgroups $(p^n - 1) q$? I understand that there are $q$ many of them and that the intersection of all of them is trivial, but why can't they have pairwise nontrivial intersection? In that case, we will be double counting elements.

Answer (score 0):

A consequence of one of Sylow's theorems is that if there is exactly one $p$-Sylow subgroup $H$ of $G$, then is it normal. Can you do the rest?

Comment: I used such fact when proving the case $p>q$, but I wouldn't know how to apply it to $p<q$. Also, technically the result you mention doesn't need Sylow Theory.